# primary, candidate and superkey

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key, create-table

I have the following table and I wanted to know how to know to get the primary key, superkey and candidate key.

I know that candidate key is the minimum of superkey.

Would this be correct primary key `PlaceId CountyId`, candidate key `PlaceId, CountyId, Date` and superkey being `PlaceId, CountyId, Date, Attendees`?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visits` (
  `PlaceId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountyId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Attendees` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

INSERT INTO `visits` (`PlaceId`, `CountyId`, `Date`, `Attendees`) VALUES
('Bangor', 'Gwynedd', '2012-05-03', '34'),
('Bangor', 'Gwynedd', '2012-05-04', '24'),
('Rhyl', 'Denbighshire', '2012-05-06', '14');
```

Comment: (PlaceId, CountyId) is not a key since there are 2 rows with the same values for these.  Whether CountyId belongs in the keys depends on whether it is functionally dependent on PlaceId or not (it appears to be on the basis of the 4 sample rows but may not be in general).

Comment: I wouldn't use any of those columns as a key, `varchar(45)` ouch!  I create new tables for each: places, countries, and attendees, and then FK back to this visits table using the int pk of each of the new tables.  you seem to have Attendees with int values, why use varchar(45) for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data you provided, and on my understanding of what *place*, *county*, *date*, and *attendee* mean, the only candidate key is {PlaceId, CountyId, Date}.

Since there's only one candidate key, that candidate key must also be the primary key.

The set of all attributes is a trivial superkey. So one superkey is {PlaceId, CountyId, Date, Attendees}. The other is {PlaceId, CountyId, Date}.

Comment: thanks 4 your help would {PlaceId, CountyId, Attendees} be a candidate key if i changed the date to default value?

Comment: @suryll: No. Your sample data would allow that, but your sample data isn't representative. You surely need to allow something like {'Bangor', 'Gwynedd', '2012-05-05', 34}; the "key" you suggest wouldn't allow that. (Same number of attendees in one place on different dates.)